# Transparency with hole

Tags: css, sass, transparency

I have a simple JQuery carousel with an overlay (to "blur" out the inactive slides).

I hope this image makes it clear:
[image]

I use this HTML as overlay:

```
<div class="l-overlay-wrapper clearfix">
   <div class="l-overlay">
      <div class="l-overlay-filter">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I use this SASS to generate my overlay:

```
.l-overlay-wrapper {
  background-color: $white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  .l-overlay {
    @include rgba-background(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.97));
    height: 500px;
    .l-overlay-filter {
      background-color: $white;
      height: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      opacity: 0.5;
      width: 640px;
    }
  }
}
```

Where the `.l-overlay-filter` is the "lighter" filter and the `.l-overlay` is the *background* overlay.

But that's not what I want. I want the `.l-overlay-filter` to be 100% transparant. In other words, I want the original image to be shown, with no overlay.

Is it possible to make this "hole" in a transparancy div?
It should be compatible up to IE8.